# How to write a function that emulates _.each() from underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, each

There is this exercise I cannot wrap my head around. 
I need to write a function that emulates the underscore.js function _.each() in a way that produces the same result and also passes the following tests:

- should iterate over an array
- should iterate over an object
- should ignore the object prototype
- should access the original collection
- should bind to context if one is passed
- should return the collection

This is the empty given function:

```
_.each= function (collection, iteratee, context) {}
```

and this is what I have written so far and do not pass any of the tests:

```
  _.each = function (collection, iteratee, context) {
    if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
      for (let key of collection) {
        console.log(key, collection.keys());
      }
    } else {
      for (let prop in collection) {
        if (collection.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          console.log(`${prop}: ${collection[prop]}`);
        }
      }
    }
    return collection
  };
```

What I am trying to do here is to iterate through the array with for of loop, and through the object with for in loop ignoring the object prototype properties. 
I actually do not want to have the solution of the problem nor specific code, just a push in the right direction, and then find the solution myself.
I am pretty new to JS and I admit I cannot really think of a way to face this problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: return collection should be easy?  .bind the function?  the rest seems to be there already

Comment: bind the function I didn't even start writing it because it keeps telling me all the tests failed, so I first wanted to fix the function to pass at least the first three tests: 
should iterate over an array
should iterate over an object
should ignore the object prototype

Comment: I suspect it's failing some of the tests because you're not actually making use of `iteratee` and the tests are leveraging that argument to check your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint. I hope this pushes you in the right direction.

```js
_.each = function (collection, iteratee, context) {
  // you're going to want something that checks length of arguments and binds context to iteratee here

  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (let key of collection) { /* you're gonna need the index later so consider using
                                     for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {...} */

      console.log(key, collection.keys()); // replace this line with calling iteratee with item, i, and collection
    }
  } else {
    for (let prop in collection) {
      if (collection.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        console.log(`${prop}: ${collection[prop]}`); // replace this line with calling iteratee with collection[prop], prop, and collection
      }
    }
  }
  return collection
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the test for an Each implementation starts by creating an example function, and an example collection, then calling your function on them. 
Example:

```
var array0 = [1,2,3];
var array1= [];
var iteratee = function (item) {
array1.push(item * 2);
}
```

When the function is called on each item, it will do the thing that has been specified. So, in this case, it pushes the result of multiplying each item by 2 into the empty array.  
The expected output of the above example would be an array1 with [2,4,6] in it. 
Since you haven't written the part when the iteratee is called, when the test runs, nothing happens.